# Creating a CSV File from a string using PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

Is this possible? or must one use a PHP library such as [thephpleague/csv](https://github.com/thephpleague/csv)?

Example, according to *[PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/#writing-a-csv-file)*'s documentation:

```
$reader      = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($file);

$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv($spreadsheet);
$writer->setUseBOM(true);
$writer->setDelimiter(',');
$writer->setEnclosure('');
$writer->setLineEnding("\r\n");
$writer->setSheetIndex(0);

$writer->save('test.csv');
```

As you can see this completely counter-productive as the `load()` method requires an actual `$file` to do essentially the same thing.

Is there a way to use `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv()` without using the spreadsheet and instead using a string containing CSV data?

Thanks in advance for all positive inputs and suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to load a file, you can create an empty Spreadsheet object directly by using

```
$spreadsheet = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
```

as shown in the "Hello World" example in the [PHPSPreadsheet documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#getting-started)

But if all you want to do is write a csv file; then you're far better using PHP's built-in `fputcsv()` function than a library designed to manipulate genuine spreadsheets with multiple worksheets, formatting, formulae, and working with multiple different file formats, etc.

Or for simply writing a string that's already concatenated (are you sure that you've quoted everything that needs quoting, and escaped everything that needs escaping), just use `fwrite()`.

Counter-productive is building your own csv string and then using a spreadsheet library to write each line.

Comment: Thank you for the straightforward explanation and input! Exactly what I was looking for as an answer :]

Answer (score 0):

from the docs:
https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/#csv-comma-separated-values

You can also treat a string as if it were the contents of a CSV file as follows:

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv();
$spreadsheet = $reader->loadSpreadsheetFromString($data);
```